# Swift 4 SQLITE query output fails with where clause

Tags: sql, swift, sqlite, filter

I am new to iOS and SWIFT but making progress.

I use SQLITE database to store employee details. While querying data, I need to filter output with a WHERE clause restricting it to just one row. The query doesn't give any output, but if I remove the WHERE clause, it works. I need to be able to filter query output to a specific i-phone of user.

This is a static function within a class I use in many places across the App.
My Code:

```
// ***********************************
static func queryPhoneOwner() {
     let queryPhoneOwnerString = "SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, FULL_NAME, LOCATION, UUID FROM MT_PHONE_OWNER WHERE UUID = ?"
    var queryPhoneOwnerStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil
    let db = DatabaseClass.openDatabase()
    var vUUID: String = " "
    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, queryPhoneOwnerString, -1, &queryPhoneOwnerStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {

        if let uuid = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString {

            vUUID = uuid
        }

         sqlite3_bind_text(queryPhoneOwnerStatement, 1, vUUID, -1, nil)

        while (sqlite3_step(queryPhoneOwnerStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            let queryResultCol1 = sqlite3_column_text(queryPhoneOwnerStatement, 0)
            let vOwnerEmployeeId = String(cString: queryResultCol1!)

            let queryResultCol2 = sqlite3_column_text(queryPhoneOwnerStatement, 1)
            let vOwnerFullName = String(cString: queryResultCol2!)

            let queryResultCol3 = sqlite3_column_text(queryPhoneOwnerStatement, 2)
            let vOwnerLocation = String(cString: queryResultCol3!)

            let queryResultCol4 = sqlite3_column_text(queryPhoneOwnerStatement, 3)
            let vOwnerUuid = String(cString: queryResultCol4!)

// and the code continues..
// FYI, Table columns pasted here from table creation process: "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MT_PHONE_OWNER (EMPLOYEE_ID VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY, FULL_NAME VARCHAR(50), LOCATION VARCHAR(15), UUID VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL)"
//********************************************
```

Comment: You are not applying a condition to 'queryPhoneOwnerString.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Avoid using `SELECT * FROM` in your code. Explicitly list the fields you wish to query. This ensures you get specific values in a specific order which is important in your `sqlite3_column_text` usage.
2. Your query has one parameter. This means that your `sqlite3_bind_text` index must match. You are passing `4` but it needs to be `1`.
3. Not really a problem but the `?` doesn't need to be in parentheses in your query.
4. Be careful force unwrapping the results of `sqlite3_column_text`. There could be NULL values in the database which is why the result is optional. If the column is setup as `NOT NULL` then this is probably OK since the value will never be `nil`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt response and comments. I changed the query to ---let queryPhoneOwnerString = "SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, FULL_NAME, LOCATION, UUID FROM MT_PHONE_OWNER WHERE UUID = ?" --- and bind text as -- sqlite3_bind_text(queryPhoneOwnerStatement, 1, vUUID, -1, nil) --, but I still have the same issue. !!??

Comment: I also edited my original posting with corrected code

Comment: I also tried changing sql query to have first column as UUID (SELECT UUID, EMPLOYEE_ID,....) etc instead of SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, ....

Comment: Verify the value of `vUUID` that you bind to the query. Are you sure there really is a matching record in the database?

Comment: I checked again. There was a problem in data in table, but your suggestion helped getting past the issue. Thank you..